# Block assignation using network topology

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

If I well understood principles when applying network topology, blocks are written:

- On the client server if hosting a datanode
- On a second server defined on a different rack
- On a third server defined on the same rack as #2

Is this policy configurable or it is “hard-written” in class? Of course, I do not want to modify any class by myself…

Basically, I would like to:

1. Take into account datacenter (according to what I read, HDFS do not care datacenters even if using network topology)
2. Force the write in 3 distinct racks

How do I do that?

Comment: HDFS cares about data-localization when processing by Map Reduce..Replication factor is configurable and by default it is 3 in cluster by `dfs.replication`

Answer (score 0):

There is a capability to override the baseline block allocation algorithm but it does involve writing quite a bit of Java code and there aren't any real good examples out there.  Here is a blog with a link to the JIRA ticket explaining the enhancement:

- http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/hdfs-block-replica-placement-in-your.html
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385

Comment: Thanks David... I just see your post that answers correctly to my question. I had the same conclusion but I am a little fearful for writing my own class for assigning block. Firstly I used HDP and I prefer keeping the distrib as-is... and I am not sure that a dedicated class will be correctly called in all cases (of instance during a file writing, but also during the balancing stage when I add a datanode, and so on). Thank again...